# How to set output path of cmake / qt4 command QT4_WRAP_UI

Tags: user-interface, qt4, cmake

I use the cmake command QT4_WRAP_UI. Is there an option to control the output path of the generated header files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is `QT4_WRAP_UI` source code:

```
MACRO (QT4_WRAP_UI outfiles )
  QT4_EXTRACT_OPTIONS(ui_files ui_options ${ARGN})

  FOREACH (it ${ui_files})
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(outfile ${it} NAME_WE)
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(infile ${it} ABSOLUTE)
    SET(outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ui_${outfile}.h) # Here we set output
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${outfile}
      COMMAND ${QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS ${ui_options} -o ${outfile} ${infile}
      MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${infile})
    SET(${outfiles} ${${outfiles}} ${outfile})
  ENDFOREACH (it)

ENDMACRO (QT4_WRAP_UI)
```

As you can see, the `outfile` variable is build from `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` variable. You can create a custom macro that will replace that line.

Answer (score 3):

I had to find a solution to this. I did create a custom macro, but I think it would be nicer if the macro in cmake upstream would handle this automagically.

See my proposal [here](http://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14760)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` to the include dir:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: The question is if it is possible to control the output path of the `QT4_WRAP_UI` macro. Therefore, including the default directory for the generated files does not anser the question.